# How to configure GoDaddy domain to point to a specific github pages repository?

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, github

We have a [github repository](https://github.com/nordible/nordible.github.io) which is configured to point to [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/):

[image]

Hitting [nordible.github.io](http://nordible.github.io) successfully lands to [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/).

> So, we've successfully connected a github website to a custom domain!

[image]

The domain [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/) is with [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com).

Now, what steps shall we take at [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com) side to make [nordible.com](http://nordible.com/) show the pages from [nordible.github.io](http://nordible.github.io)?

We noticed that, there are ways to [redirect a domain to a specific Github page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86875/51058). However, we need a direct non-redirecting way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `A` dns zone record for `nordible.com.` with value `184.168.221.49` and add two `A` records: first with `192.30.252.153`, then `192.30.252.154`. You can add extra subdomains for pointing to GitHub Pages adding a `CNAME` record using `nordible.github.io` for value.

According to the current content, be sure that in GitHub Pages setup you specified `master` as the source branch.

See also [Setting up an apex domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/) and [Using a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) for wider explanation.